# ut sibi complaceam in Stabat Mater

Tags: syntax

Verse 10 of the Stabat Mater reads:
Fac ut ardeat cor meum/
in amando Christum Deum/
ut sibi complaceam.
I am stumped by "sibi" in line 3. Most translations give "that I may please **him**", but sibi seems to be a dative relexive. How should the line be interpreted?

Comment: You're right this is strange! I've found a few sources (like [this one](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5717872c/texteBrut)) that have "ut illi complaceam" in this line, which makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Looking through Google Books, it appears that (a) a number of people have been irritated by this over the years, and (b) explanations are along the lines of (1) the author was Italian, (b) *sibi* for *ei* or *ipsi* is often seen in Medieaval Latin (really?), or (3) *sibi* for *ei* or *ipsi* is often seen in Late Latin and the Vulgate (really???).

Comment: I. J. G. Scheller (tr. George Walker), *A Copious Latin Grammar, 2nd ed.*, Vol. 1, London: J. Murray 1838, [pp. 278-279](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Copious_Latin_Grammar/8u8do2JNVLUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA278&printsec=frontcover): "This is the rule to which the learner should be accustomed before he notices the exceptions in the ancients. When for instance no obscurity is likely to arise, sui, sibi, &c. may be used for eius, ei, &c.: [...] Examples of this kind are innumerable in the ancients, e.g. [*many examples*] On the contrary ei &c. are used for sibi &c.: [*a few examples*] "

Comment: @njuffa Looks like the beginning of an answer.

Comment: I came across a claim that in the High Middle Ages / Late Middle Ages (so around the time *Stabat Mater* originated in the 13th century) "sibi" came to be used freely in place of "ei", citing [Stotz 4 IX § 38.5], which apparently is volume 4 of Peter Stotz, *Handbuch zur lateinischen Sprache des Mittelalters*, C. H. Beck 1996. Does anyone here have access to this comprehensive (five volume) work on medieval Latin?